# Twitter bootstrap accordion fixed sizes in percentages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height, accordion

Using the twitter bootstrap I'm trying to create an accordion that when expanded will take up `80%` on the screen `height`. So far I haven't been able to find a way to make it co-operate with `%`.
Fixed heights work fine but without doing calculations to figure out what 80% of the screen height will be it's pretty pointless.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle btn-warning btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                RETURNED RESULTS
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                WRITE RESPONSE
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
#admin-response{
    width:60%;
    min-width:400px;
    margin-left:10%;
    height:85%;
    float:left;
}
#admin-response .accordion-inner{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#admin-response .accordion-body.in.collapse{
    min-height:85%;
}​
```

I've created a fiddle that shows what I have locally

http://jsfiddle.net/bpSjn/1/

The accordion mockup is the same as the example given by twitter. With a few minor changes for css.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle here with simple jQuery to measure window Height

```
var viewportHeight = $(window).height() * 0.8;
$('.accordion').css('max-height', viewportHeight);
$('.accordion').css('min-height', viewportHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bpSjn/31/

Also note the deleted heights in the CSS